# using backslashes with bash and mysql

Tags: mysql, bash, escaping, backslash

This is boggling my mind today.
I have a bash script to set a value in a MySQL table:
The value I have to set is to UNC path with a trailing backslash: \\$HOSTNAME\path\

Inside mysql the query works:

```
update mytable SET myvalue = '\\\\MYSERVER\\path\\' WHERE ID=10;
```

But from bash, it fails:

```
mysql -e "update mytable SET myvalue = '\\\\$HOSTNAME\\path\\' WHERE ID=10;"
```

MySQL gives a syntax error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
right syntax to use near ''\\MYSERVER\path\' WHERE ID=10' at line 1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's inside double quotes, you'll need to double all those backslashes.

If you don't need to expand any shell variables, swap the single and double quotes instead.

Comment: That's one of the problems; I do have shell variables:  "\\\\$HOSTNAME\\path\\"

Comment: Unbelieveably, it takes a lot of backslashes to do this:  mysql -e "SELECT '\\\\\\\\$HOSTNAME\\\\path\\\\'"

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -e 'SELECT "\\\\server\\path\\"'
mysql -e 'update mytable SET myvalue = "\\\\server\\path\\" WHERE ID=10;'
```